# Howto add batch \section and \input in a Latex document

Tags: sectioning, packages, input

I'm working on a Cook Book for my recipes. I use the cuisine package and all my recipes are in seperated files in seperated directories. To include the files in latex per hands is not the problem. But i like to automate it. Because the fies are a "work in progress" and adding or changing often. I found a bash script here: `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298792/sort-sections-according-to-alphabetical-order/299600#299600`. But this doesn't include directories.
Here is an example from my file structure:

`tellan@tellan1:~/Dokumente/kochen/buch/buch$ ls -1g *`

> Suppen_Eintoepfe:
>   insgesamt 12K
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 tellan  539 Jul 21  2017 Chilieconcarne.txt
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 tellan 1,3K Jul 21  2017 Waterzooi.txt
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 tellan  912 Nov  8 12:45   Wild_Consomme_Mit_Bratapfelkloesschen.txt
>
> Teige_Und_Massen:
>   insgesamt 28K
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 tellan  848 Jul 22  2017 Biskuitteig.txt
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 tellan  633 Jul 22  2017 Brandteig.txt
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 tellan  226 Okt  5 15:29 Grundfarce.txt

This is my basic latex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,parskip,openany]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumber,contents,index]{cuisine}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\Displ@ySt@p}{\arabic{st@pnumber}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\recipetitlefont}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\title{Kochbuch}
\author{Ich}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Nicht dein Kochbuch}
\newpage

\section{Vorspeisen Und Salate}
\input {Vorspeisen_Und_Salate/7-Layer-Dip.txt}
\input {Kuchen/Banana_Fudge_Brownies.txt}
\input {Kuchen/Bananen-Haferflocken-Muffins.txt}

\section{Soßen}
\input {Sossen/Asiatische_Bbq-Sosse.txt}
\input {Sossen/Barbecue-Sosse_Aus_Fertigprodukten.txt}
\input {Sossen/Currysosse_Nr_1.txt}

\section{Ect}
\input {Ect/Mengenangaben.txt}
\input {Ect/backformen.txt}
\input {Ect/umrechnungstabelle_us.txt}

\end{document}
```

per Hands is it working like a charme. I know it is not the cleanest command structure, but its working. Until know i can input the file via bash, but that doesnt include the directories as */section* input.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" > sectionlist.tex
for sfile in `ls -1 */*.txt | cut -f 1 -d . | sort -d`
do
    echo "\input {$sfile.txt}" >> sectionlist.tex
done
```

Thanks to Masroor for the script. I'm working with sed syntaxes as well. But without any success until now. I have not the best programming skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this isn't really a (La)TeX question, but does this script do what you're asking for?

The first part just creates the directories/files you mentioned (if they don't already exist, otherwise it does nothing). The second part creates a tex-file that contains `\section{<dirname with spaces instead of underscores>}` for every directory and `\input{<filename>}` for every text file in these directories.

```
#!/bin/bash

########################################
## Remove this for the final version: ##
########################################
mkdir -p "Suppen_Eintoepfe" "Teige_und_Massen"
touch "Suppen_Eintoepfe/Chilieconcarne.txt" "Suppen_Eintoepfe/Waterzooi.txt" "Suppen_Eintoepfe/Wild_Consomme_Mit_Bratapfelkloesschen.txt"
touch "Teige_und_Massen/Biskuitteig.txt" "Teige_und_Massen/Brandteig.txt" "Grundfarce.txt"
########################################

echo "%% This file was automatically generated by $(basename "$0")" > sectionlist.tex
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -c 3- | sort -df | while read -r sdir; do
    txtfilefound=false #*
    find "$sdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' | cut -f 1 -d . | sort -df | while read -r sfile; do
        if [ "$txtfilefound" = false ]; then #*
            echo $'\n'"\\section{${sdir//_/ }}" >> sectionlist.tex #*
            txtfilefound=true #*
        fi #*
        echo "\\input{$sfile.txt}" >> sectionlist.tex
    done
done
```

After running this, the contents of `sectionlist.tex` will be:

```
%% This file was automatically generated by makesectionlist.sh

\section{Suppen Eintoepfe}
\input{Suppen_Eintoepfe/Chilieconcarne.txt}
\input{Suppen_Eintoepfe/Waterzooi.txt}
\input{Suppen_Eintoepfe/Wild_Consomme_Mit_Bratapfelkloesschen.txt}

\section{Teige und Massen}
\input{Teige_und_Massen/Biskuitteig.txt}
\input{Teige_und_Massen/Brandteig.txt}
```

This might not work that well if you've got section titles with special characters though (which seems likely since the recipe names are in German). If that is a problem you could consider creating a file called `0title.txt` in every directory containing just `\section{<Section title>}`, with `<Section title>` replaced by whatever the title for that section should be. This file would be sorted before the files that start with a letter. If you do this you should remove all the lines marked by `#*` above.

Note: `sort -d` is case sensitive, which means that it sorts all capital letters before all lowercase letters. Since this is probably not what you want, I've used `sort -df` instead.