Reverse the order of the sections
I want to reverse the order of the sections in my document. Is it possible to have a command or environment reversed for doing in the following way:
main.tex
\documentclass{article}

# packages and codes needed for the custom environment `reversed`

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
\begin{reversed}
    \input{dates/230701}
    \input{dates/240310}
    \input{dates/240720}
\end{reversed}

\end{document}

In the subdirectory dates, the following files are kept.
230701.tex
\section{(01.07.23) Section A}
Contents of section A...

240310.tex
\section{(10.03.24) Section B}
Contents of section B...

240720.tex
\section{(20.07.24) Section C}
Contents of section C...

From this, I would like to get the output as the same as it would be from:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
% \begin{reversed}
    \input{dates/240720}
    \input{dates/240310}
    \input{dates/230701}
% \end{reversed}

\end{document}

Does such a command already exist in any package? If not, how to make such a custom command to reverse their order?

maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298792/sort-sections-according-to-alphabetical-order could give some inspiration

With \section commands this is hard to be done, because the content of a section is only limited implicit by starting a new section or ending the document or maybe also by other commands like \appendix, \printindex etc. This is the reason why the answers to the similar question linked by @samcarter use additional structural changes.

tex does not hold the document in memory, so normally sections are already typeset and added to the pdf before later \section commands have even been read from the source file. So it would be far more natural to re-order using your editor than to do it in tex.

You can do that manually with no pain with subdocuments (secA.tex, secB.tex, etc ...) and include them in the main file  in the desired order with  \input{secB},  \input{secA}, etc. Plain text able to folding sections also allow easy cut & paste with low risk of cut in the wrong place. Finally, LyX can  also convert very easily the section 3 as section 2 or 2.1 or whatever  from the outline pane without any cut & paste.

I have updated the structure of the MWE.

Method:

At the beginning of reversed:

Save the current meaning of \input.
Redefine \input temporarily to add the name of the input file to an expl3 sequence.


At the end of reversed:

Restore the original meaning of \input.
Reverse the sequence using the function expl3 provides for this.
Process the sequence of file names, inputting each one.




\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname1.tex}
  file 1 : should be third\par
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname2.tex}
  file 2 : should be second\par
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname3.tex}
  file 3 : should be first\par
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{230701.tex}
%   230701.tex
  
\section{(01.07.23) Section A}
Contents of section A...
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{240310.tex}
%   240310.tex

\section{(10.03.24) Section B}
Contents of section B...
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{240720.tex}
%   240720.tex

\section{(20.07.24) Section C}
Contents of section C...
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_raf_inputs_seq
\cs_new:Npn \l__raf_input_orig:n #1  {}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \raf_add_input:n #1
{
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_raf_inputs_seq { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {reversed} { }
{
  \cs_set_eq:NN \l__raf_input_orig:n \input
  \cs_set_eq:NN \input \raf_add_input:n
}{
  \seq_reverse:N \l_raf_inputs_seq
  \cs_set_eq:NN \input \l__raf_input_orig:n
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raf_inputs_seq
  {
    \file_input:n { ##1 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
Pre-Flight Check:

\begin{reversed}
  \input{\jobname1}
  \input{\jobname2}
  \input{\jobname3}
\end{reversed}

\tableofcontents 
\begin{reversed}
  \input{230701}
  \input{240310}
  \input{240720}
\end{reversed}



\end{document}


Is it recommended to keep that code before \documentclass?

@raf No. that was me screwing up. I've corrected it now. thanks for pointing it out. you might want to put it into a package, but you'd load it after \documentclass. (at least, better unless some reason not to.)

Thanks. And, how about the environments filecontents? Are they recommended to load before \documentclass?

By the way, at first sight, I got confused seeing the section sorting in your output screenshot. If you put \begin{reversed} \input{dates/230701} \input{dates/240310} \input{dates/240720} \end{reversed} instead and uploaded the screenshot, it would match with the question's MWE and be less confusing for the viewers, I guess.

@raf Yes, as I understand it, it's recommended to put filecontents before the class. However, those are only really used for examples. I've never used one in a real document.

@raf Oh, I had that and then thought it didn't match your MWE so changed it .... better now?

Thank you for the clarification. But please recheck why the (10.03.24) Section B appears first at your ToC in the screenshot. It should be the (20.07.24) Section C instead.

@raf no idea. I have issues with images due to an Okular bug. I redid it and it seems fine now. can only think I somehow got a stale image before. or maybe I forgot to recompile.

I see. Thank you for the update.
