# Random question ordering with Exam class and probsoln package

Tags: exam, probsoln

I'm using the `exam` class with the `probsoln` package to make quizzes with a random subset of the material students should know. If I do something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{probsoln}

\begin{document}


        \header{English 213}{Quiz on vocab lists 1--2}{Fall 2017}


    \loadrandomproblems{5}{prob_set_1.tex}
    \loadrandomproblems{5}{prob_set_2.tex}


    \begin{questions}
    \foreachproblem{\question[1]\thisproblem\dotfill}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I get five random problems from problem set 1, followed by five random problems from problem set 2. Is there a way to randomize the question order for both sets of problems, so the problems from lists 1 and 2 are all mixed together?

I did try

```
\loadrandomproblems{10}{prob_set_1.tex,prob_set_2.tex}
```

but that produced an error.

Comment: You might try globbing (such as `prob_set_*.tex`). If that doesn't work, you will probably have to merge the files. On Linux/Unix, you could do this using a shell command: `\immediatewrite18 cat prob_set_*.tex > /tmp/problems.tex` and then `\loadrandomproblems{10}{/tmp/problems.tex}`. You need to run Tex with the `--shell-escape` option for this to work.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer What if I had three problem sets and only wanted to use two of them? That's just a merging situation, right?

Comment: In that case, you would have name both files explicitly: `cat a.tex b.tex > merged.tex`. The idea is simply that `cat` can merge any number of files into a single one, which gets you around the limitation of the `\loadrandomproblems` command. But it might be good to ask the package author, Nicola Talbot, whether the capacity to load multiple files could be built into the package itself.

Comment: This could be adapted, possibly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296125/how-to-randomize-the-order-of-subsections/296165?s=2|1.5258#296165

Comment: I'll see if I can modify the code to allow a comma-separated list. Another possibility you might want to consider is to convert from `probsoln` to `datatool` (via `datatooltk`). That will give you more flexibility. See [Using the datatool Package for Exams or Assignment Sheets](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatoolexam.shtml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from v3.05 (2017-07-10) you can supply a comma-separated list of file names:

```
\loadrandomproblems{10}{prob_set_1.tex,prob_set_2.tex}
```

Here's a temporary fix until the new version becomes available:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{probsoln}

\begin{document}


        \header{English 213}{Quiz on vocab lists 1--2}{Fall 2017}


    \let\orginput\input
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*{\input}[1]{\@for\thisfile:=#1\do{\orginput{\thisfile}}}
    \loadrandomproblems{10}{prob_set_1.tex,prob_set_2.tex}
    \makeatother
    \let\input\orginput

    \begin{questions}
    \foreachproblem{\question[1]\thisproblem\dotfill}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```