# Points in exam class using probsoln

Tags: exam, probsoln, points

This is an extension and accidently asked originally as part of [Random question ordering with Exam class and probsoln package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379881/random-question-ordering-with-exam-class-and-probsoln-package/403806#403806)
As an additional question, to typeset a question in the exam class, I would have

```
\question[x] How many beans make five?
```

When setting up the database, I have tried:

```
[x] How many beans make five?
```

My reasoning would be that the code above

```
\begin{questions}
    \foreachproblem{\question\thisproblem\dotfill}
\end{questions}
```

would put the point value in.  Alas, this does not work!
I have used a small definition

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\mk}[1]{\marginnote{\fbox{#1}}}
```

which sort of works, but I would like to use the feature of the exam package to add the points.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this problem can be overcome?

Comment: It might be easier to replace probsoln than adapt it.

Comment: `\thisproblem` is in the form `\useproblem[` *db* `]{` *label* `}` which hides the initial `[x]` from `\question`.