# How to order the items of the second level of enumerate according to a prescribed order

Tags: enumerate

Suppose that I have the following document:

1. Examples.

   a) Example 1;

   b) Example 2;

   c) Example 3;

   d) Example 4.

In a different version of the document, I want the following:

1. Examples.

   a) Example 4;

   b) Example 3;

   c) Example 1;

   d) Example 2.

(Please, notice the change of order.)

That is, in the second version of the document, I want to instruct LaTeX to write the items according to the sequence D-C-A-B. Is that possible without changing the code of enumerate of the first document? That is, without changing the following code?

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item Examples.

\begin{enumerate}

\item Example 1;

\item Example 2;

\item Example 3;

\item Example 4.

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: So you want to generate it randomly?

Comment: No randomly, but deterministically.

Comment: In that case, I seriously wonder why you don't just rearrange the `\item`s. That is inarguably the simplest and cleanest solution.

Comment: If it is deterministic, there must be a rule. What is it?

Comment: The example given here is minimal. The real one is much more complicated: I have many, many items, from which I want to produce several versions. Rearranging the items manually is not very practical.

Comment: The rule, in my example, is: D-C-A-B.

Comment: You say your actual document is "much more complicated". How would your D-C-A-B rule then apply to your real document?

Comment: To amplify of @siracusa's comment, if your list has 100 items, are you prepared to provide a rule with 100 entries to specify the order?  If so, that problem is do-able.  But if not, you need to help us out with defining the rule more precisely.

Comment: For a randomly sorted list, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296125/how-to-randomize-the-order-of-subsections.  One could replace the filenames with macros.

Comment: Suppose that one has an enumerate with 10 items, with each item having a nested enumerate with 4 items. And consider the following rule: 

1 C A D B

2 A B D C

3 C D A B

4 D B A C

5 C D A B

6 B A C D

7 D A B C

8 C B A D

9 A B D C

10 B A D C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the OP literally ("The rule, in my example, is: D-C-A-B"), that the list order is pre-specified, here is a `listofitems` approach for sorting the pre-specified list.  Note, as shown in the MWE, the pre-specified list can be given directly as the environment argument, or stored in a macro in advance, which is passed in its stead.

Note, the approach can handle optional arguments to `\item`, as well.

EDITED to allow multiple paragraphs in each item, as well as `tabular`s, etc.

I have set up the punctuation in the following way...I recommend omitting trailing punctuation from `\item`s of the `prenumerate` input, and just inserting them as part of the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\NewEnviron{prenumerate}[1]{%
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist\listorder{#1}%
  \setsepchar{\item||\par\item}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter*\expandafter
    \prenumlist\expandafter{\expandafter\item\expandafter\relax\BODY}%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \foreachitem\x\in\listorder[]{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\item 
      \prenumlist[\the\numexpr\x+1\relax]%
    \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\listorder[]\relax.\else;\fi%
  }%
  \end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\preordA{4,3,1,2}
\newcommand\preordB{3,1,4,2}
\begin{prenumerate}{\preordA}
\item Example 1

Multiple paragraphs

and another paragraph
\item Example 2
\item Example 3---tabular

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
 \hline
  a & b\\c & d\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\item Example 4
\end{prenumerate}

The prenumerate environment can be embedded inside enumerate, but
not nested with other prenumerates.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Examples.
\begin{prenumerate}{4,3,1,2}

\item Example 1

\item Example 2
\item Example 3
\item Example 4

\end{prenumerate}
\item Examples ordered differently.
\begin{prenumerate}{\preordB}
\item Example 1
\item Example 2
\item[$\bullet$] Example 3
\item Example 4
\end{prenumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The items have tables and are not simple paragraphs. Moreover, your approach requires the user to define the new order in each prenumerate environment; if one has 100 prenumerate environments, that is not practical -- it would be better to have the order for all prenumerate environments defined in a single place.

Comment: @PaulSmith i believe I have addressed the issues you raise here.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a conflict with package `multicols`, which I would like to use inside `prenumerate`.

Comment: If one inserts `\begin{multicols}{#2}` and `\end{multicols}` inside the enumerate environment where you define the `prenumerate` environment, then it works excellently!