# How to order the items of both first and second level of enumerate according to a prescribed order?

Tags: enumerate

This question is closely related to a previous one:

[How to order the items of the second level of enumerate according to a prescribed order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487762/how-to-order-the-items-of-the-second-level-of-enumerate-according-to-a-prescribed)

The solution proposed by Steven B. Segletes works excellently when only the second level items are required to obey to a prescribed order. Steven himself tells us:

"The prenumerate environment can be embedded inside enumerate, but not nested with other prenumerates."

So, how to proceed when one wants

1. Example set 1.

   (a) Example set 1-a);

   (b) Example set 1-b);

   (c) Example set 1-c);

   (d) Example set 1-d).
2. Example set 2.

   (a) Example set 2-a);

   (b) Example set 2-b);

   (c) Example set 2-c);

   (d) Example set 2-d).

following rule (as an example):

2B,2C,2A,2D,1C,1D,1A,1B,

which would have produced the following output:

1. Example set 2.

   (a) Example set 2-b);

   (b) Example set 2-c);

   (c) Example set 2-a);

   (d) Example set 2-d).
2. Example set 1.

   (a) Example set 1-c);

   (b) Example set 1-d);

   (c) Example set 1-a);

   (d) Example set 1-b).

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prior (referenced by the OP) answer can be used with a slight syntax variation.  Namely, the inner `prenumerate`s need to me enclosed in their own group.

I also added an optional argument to `prenumerate` to suppress the trailing auto-punctuation, since punctuation following an inner `prenumerate` falls on a subsequent line all by itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\NewEnviron{prenumerate}[2][\relax]{%
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist\listorder{#2}%
  \setsepchar{\item||\par\item}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter
    \prenumlist\expandafter{\expandafter\item\expandafter\relax\BODY}%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \foreachitem\x\in\listorder[]{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\item 
      \prenumlist[\the\numexpr\x+1\relax]%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\listorder[]\relax.\else;\fi\fi%
  }%
  \end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\preordB{3,1,4,2}

To nest prenumerate environments, group the inner environments.
Also, optional argument provided to suppress trailing auto-punctuation.

\begin{prenumerate}[x]{2,1}
\item Examples.
{\begin{prenumerate}{4,3,1,2}

\item Example 1

\item Example 2
\item Example 3
\item Example 4

\end{prenumerate}}
\item Examples ordered differently.
{\begin{prenumerate}{\preordB}
\item Example 1
\item Example 2
\item[$\bullet$] Example 3
\item Example 4
\end{prenumerate}}
\end{prenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

User PaulSmith asks if the `prenumerate` environment can be reworked with a deferred output; that is, saved for later use.  With a lot of `\expandafter`s, the answer is yes.

I name this environment `renumerate` and it takes an extra mandatory argument, a unique macro name used to store internal list data.  For example, here I provide the name `\z`:

```
\begin{renumerate}[x]{2,1}{\z}
\item The first

\item the second
\end{renumerate}
```

Later, when the list is desired, it is to be recalled with the macro `\zlist`, essentially tacking the word `list` onto the end of the unique macro name provided.

In the MWE, I use a normal `prenumerate`.  Then I create 2 `renumerate`s, and later present the second one first, followed by the first one (using the `resume` key of `enumitem`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,environ,enumitem}
\NewEnviron{prenumerate}[2][\relax]{%
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist\listorder{#2}%
  \setsepchar{\item||\par\item}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter
    \prenumlist\expandafter{\expandafter\item\expandafter\relax\BODY}%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \foreachitem\x\in\listorder[]{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\item 
      \prenumlist[\the\numexpr\x+1\relax]%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\listorder[]\relax.\else;\fi\fi%
  }%
  \end{enumerate}
}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{renumerate}[3][\relax]{%
  \edef\tmp{\expandafter\@gobble\string#3}%
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \greadlist#3{#2}%
  \setsepchar{\item||\par\item}%
  \expandafter\greadlist\csname prenum\tmp\expandafter
    \endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter\item\expandafter\relax\BODY}%
  \def\tempA{\begin{enumerate}\foreachitem\x\in#3[]}%
  \def\tempB{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\item}%
  \def\tempC{\csname prenum}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname \tmp list\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \endcsname\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\tempA\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\tempB\expandafter
      \tempC\tmp[\the\numexpr\x+1\relax]\endcsname%
      \ifx\relax#1\relax\ifnum\xcnt=\listlen#3[]\relax.\else;\fi\fi%
  }%
  \end{enumerate}
}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Here is one that is not deferred:
\newcommand\preordB{3,1,4,2}

To nest prenumerate environments, group the inner environments.
Also, optional argument provided to suppress trailing auto-punctuation.

\begin{prenumerate}[x]{2,1}
\item Examples.
{\begin{prenumerate}{4,3,1,2}

\item Example 1

\item Example 2
\item Example 3
\item Example 4

\end{prenumerate}}
\item Examples ordered differently.
{\begin{prenumerate}{\preordB}
\item Example 1
\item Example 2
\item[$\bullet$] Example 3
\item Example 4
\end{prenumerate}}
\end{prenumerate}

\hrulefill

\begin{renumerate}[x]{2,1}{\z}
\item The first

\item the second
\end{renumerate}

Saved the first renumerate

\hrulefill

\begin{renumerate}[x]{2,1}{\zz}
\item Examples.
{\begin{prenumerate}{4,3,1,2}

\item Example 1

\item Example 2
\item Example 3
\item Example 4

\end{prenumerate}}
\item Examples ordered differently.
{\begin{prenumerate}{\preordB}
\item Example 1
\item Example 2
\item[$\bullet$] Example 3
\item Example 4
\end{prenumerate}}
\end{renumerate}

Saved the second renumerate.

\hrulefill

Now we present the 2nd

\zzlist

Now here is the first:\setlist{resume}

\zlist

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works greatly! But suppose now, to finish this question, that one wants to add an optional argument to `prenumerate` with the number of columns to used with package `multicol` inside the second level of `prenumerate` environment: the optional argument would indicate the number of columns; the absence of the optional argument would mean not using the `multicols` environment at all inside the second level of `prenumerate`.

Comment: @PaulSmith I am not a `multicol` expert.

Comment: By inserting `\ifnum #1>1 \begin{multicols}{#1} \fi` just before `\begin{enumerate}` and `\ifnum #1>1 \end{multicols} \fi` just after `\end{enumerate}`, where #1 is an optional argument, I get precisely what I want. Thanks, Steven!

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Unfortunately, an error occur when, inside an item, one inserts `\begin{lstlisting} some code \end{lstlisting}`. Any solution?

Comment: @PaulSmith Is the `listlisting` pure verbatim stuff, or does it have syntax highlighting or other features that differentiates it from pure verbatim?

Comment: @StevenBSegletes I guess it is only pure verbatim.

Comment: @PaulSmith In the preamble: `\usepackage{verbatimbox,stackengine}`.  In the document, but outside of the `prenumerate`, this: `\begin{myverbbox}{\listingA}
  THis $
  is ^
  my&
  Code\\
\end{myverbbox}`.  Then, inside the `prenumerate`, this: `\item \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\listingA}`.  Will not however break the verbatim in the middle across a page boundary.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Thanks. However, that is not very practical, since I have too many listings. I saw somewhere that, with package `cprotect`, the issue can be fixed. But I do not know how to hack your code with `\cprotect`.

Comment: @PaulSmith I tried several ways to get `\cprotect` compatible with `environ` package.  So far, no luck.

Comment: @PaulSmith I got `\cprotEnv` to work with `environ` environments...however, doesn't want to work with `prenumerate`, perhaps because the `listofitems` package plays a number of `\catcode` games itself.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes So, there is no solution?

Comment: @PaulSmith I have found no solution via `\cprotv`, only via `verbatimbox`.  If you think about it though, setting up all your code fragments in advance, and then invoking them by what amounts to a label (the given macro name) is no different than setting up a bibliography.

Comment: @PaulSmith I have investigated more.  The issue seems to be (and I am no expert to know for sure) that while `listofitems` can absorb and parse the code that comprises a verbatim stream, the linefeeds of the original code are turned into spaces during absorption, in the traditional LaTeX way.  Then, when trying to regurgitate the verbatim code from the saved array variable, it is unable to find the `\end{verbatim}` because the linefeeds are not present in the array variable.  Attempts to add `^^J` or `^^M` to the input stream have not been successful.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Thanks! It would be great if a solution came across, since it is not very convenient the `verbatimbox` solution. You compare that with a bibliography, but while the bibliography tends to be stationary during the document's edition time, the code inserted in the 'listings` environment may be always changing.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes I have another question to you: Is it possible to show only a few items instead of all. I mean the following: Suppose one has 10 items in the first level; can one show only the 1, 3, 4, 8?

Comment: @PaulSmith Yes, it already does that, if your argument to `prenumerate` only lists some of the item numbers.  Try `\begin{prenumerate}{4,1}

\item Example 1

\item Example 2
\item Example 3
\item Example 4

\end{prenumerate}`

Comment: @StevenBSegletes I have just confirmed that, and works. That is great!

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Should one expect `prenumerate` respect `\setlist[enumerate]{beginpenalty=10000}` of `enumitem` package? Apparently, it does not!

Comment: @PaulSmith I do not use that package, but I will say that embedded in `prenumerate` is `enumerate`, and so I would think that any [prior] change that globally affects `enumerate` should also affect `prenumerate`.  I am assuming that the `setlist` macro is typically set in the preamble before the document gets underway?

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Is it possible to adapt your code to accommodate the possibility of suspended enumerates? Thanks!

Comment: @PaulSmith Do you mean to create at one point in the document, and regurgitate at a later point??

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Exactly! Likewise the `resume` option of `enumitem`.

Comment: @PaulSmith The `resume` is more than I am up for, but I am thinking about the deferred/suspended option

Comment: @StevenBSegletes I only need resuming for the first level of items. Maybe, with a parameter telling `prenumerate` the starting `enumi` would be enough?

Comment: @PaulSmith please see my **SUPPLEMENT**

Comment: @PaulSmith To use `resume`, just issue `\setlist{resume}` prior to invoking the list recall.  For example, `Now we present the 2nd

\zzlist

Now here is the first:\setlist{resume}

\zlist`

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Thanks! I have just used that in a complex document with minipages and tables inside `prenumerate` and `renumerate`, and everything works great!

Comment: @StevenBSegletes I have just rerun your Supplement example, but getting this error: `! Paragraph ended before \loi_removefirstspaces was complete.` Any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @PaulSmith I have edited my MWEs.  I had to remove instances of `expandafter*`, as the star option was causing the error,  Also, I had to add the `enumitem` package to the latter MWE.

Comment: @PaulSmith I have also verified, with V1.63 of `listofitems` (the current version), that the only change *needed* to the original MWEs was adding the `enumitem` package to the 2nd MWE.  The `\loi_removefirstspaces` error does not occur.  Perhaps also make sure you have the latest version of `listofitems`.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Thanks, but `enumitem` was already added to the 2nd MWE (in the line `\usepackage{listofitems,environ,enumitem}`).