# How to avoid splitting across different pages the first level items from the respective second order items in enumerate?

Tags: enumerate

Consider the following:

1. Example set 1

   (a) Example 1

   (b) Example 2

   (c) Example 3

   (d) Example 4
2. Example set 2

   (a) Example 1

   (b) Example 2

   (c) Example 3

   (d) Example 4

Sometimes one gets

2. Example set 2

written in a page and the following second level items written in the next page. How can one prevent that? That is, how can one avoid splitting the first level items from the respective second order items?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Please provide more information about your formatting needs. How many lines does each level-2 item tend to take up? Must all level-2 items be placed on the same page as their associated level-1 item? Or would it be ok to allow, say, a page break after the first 2 out of 4 total level-2 items?

Comment: @Mico Yes, all level-2 items be placed on the same page as their associated level-1 item. The number of lines associated to level-2 items is variable (and level-2 items  may contain tables).

Answer (score 1):

Either use/define a suitable sectioning command, this will prevent a page break after it. As an example here \minisec for the KOMA-bundle:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{33\baselineskip}

\minisec{Example set 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph{*})]
\item  Example 1
\item  Example 2
\item  Example 3
\item  Example 4
\end{enumerate}


\minisec{Example set 2}
%Example set 2

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph{*})]
\item  Example 1
\item  Example 2
\item  Example 3
\item  Example 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you want to nest enumerates, you can (with the enumitem package) set `beginpenalty` to the maximum. This will prevent a page break before a list:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{34\baselineskip}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Example set 1
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph{*})]
\item  Example 1
\item  Example 2
\item  Example 3
\item  Example 4
\end{enumerate}

\item Example set 2

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph{*}),
                  beginpenalty=10000 %<---
                 ]
\item  Example 1
\item  Example 2
\item  Example 3
\item  Example 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. My enumerate is nested, and I have tried `beginpenalty=10000`, but with no success. However, I am not using the original enumerate of `enumitem`, but `prenumerate` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488397/how-to-order-the-items-of-both-first-and-second-level-of-enumerate-according-to?rq=1

Comment: That's a new question, so ask a new question. I will *not* adapt my answer to some requirement that you didn't mention in your question directly. And better add this time a real example to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because each item is a separate paragraph, your case is one where widow/orphan penalties will have no effect.  The solution might be to use `samepage`, as in:

```
\begin{samepage}
    Example set 2

    (a) Example 1

    (b) Example 2

    (c) Example 3

    (d) Example 4

\end{samepage}
```

You might also try `\nopagebreak` between each line that you wish to keep together.