# Non-integer chapters

Tags: numbering, chapters

I am trying to get a chapter number that is not an integer.
My current code looks like this:

```
\chapter*{Example\vspace{-75pt}\\\huge Chapter 0.5}\vspace{50pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{0.5 Example}
```

However, the code is very messy, and every section needs a similar change for it to stay consistent (Thankfully I don't have any sections in the chapter *but it is a problem*).

What I am looking for is a solution that solves the first (or both) problems noted above.

EDIT: For clarification, `0.5` is just an example. More examples:

```
\chapter*{Example\vspace{-75pt}\\\huge Chapter Q}\vspace{50pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Q Example}

\chapter*{Example\vspace{-75pt}\\\huge Chapter Zero point five}\vspace{50pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Zero point five Example}

\chapter*{Example\vspace{-75pt}\\\huge Chapter Chapter}\vspace{50pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter Example}

\chapter*{Example\vspace{-75pt}\\\huge Chapter $\frac12$}\vspace{50pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{$\mathbf{\frac12}$ Example}
```

Comment: `0.5` looks like part 0, chapter 5. (Similar to how subsections are numbered.) How are the non-integer numbers incremented? If it is a fixed step across the document you could just format the output in relation to the integer numbers 1, 2, 3, …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You make a good point, what about fractions `\frac{1}{2}` instead of decimals `0.5`?

Comment: I edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: Your examples are quite diverse; it's probably easy to assume a letter numbering would be sequential (A, B, ..., Z). However, what is sequential about "zero point five" or `\frac{1}{2}`? That is, what follows it?

Comment: I an not sure what exactly do you want, but maybe `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ensuremath{\frac12}}` will do the job? (This should be done right after `\chapter{}` command)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296125/how-to-randomize-the-order-of-subsections

Comment: I could see doing this as a one-off for some reason.  But I'm confused by "section needs a similar change".

Comment: @Teepeemm Section Q.1

Comment: @nonhuman That doesn't clear things up at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing that @egreg's answer didn't work on my TeX editor I modified it to make this:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\newcommand{\customchapter}[2]{
    \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{#2}
    \chapter{#1}
}

\newcommand{\achapter}[1]{ % used after chapter
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\sthechapter}
    \chapter{#1}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\sthechapter\thechapter
    %\let\schapter\chapter
    %\newcommand{\chapter}[1]{
        %\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\sthechapter}
        %\schapter{#1}
    %} % achapter is not needed
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First}
    \customchapter{Between}{$\mathbf{\frac32}$}
    \section{Section Title}
    \chapter{chapter} % chapter 3/2
    \achapter{Second}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your TeX editor is not related to whether TeX can compile an example or not.  If egreg's example doesn't work, it would be useful to know why not.  If it's because your TeX doesn't recognize the `NewDocumentCommand` and similar commands, it would be because you have an outdated distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Not going to explain too much, but the idea is to define `\additionalchapter` that does a few things:

1. the chapter number is stepped down (so when `\chapter` is called the main number is the same as the previous one)
2. `\thechapter` is redefined to include the desired additional part;
3. `\chapter` is issued, but in its original form.

Why do we need `\standardchapter`? Because we have to add to `\chapter` the code for restoring the standard meaning of `\thechapter`.

Finally, a code for “textual” fractions is added.

**Production notes.** I use `openany` and `geometry` just to make a smaller picture of the result.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just to make smaller pictures

\NewDocumentCommand{\additionalchapter}{mO{#3}m}{%
  % #1 = suffix to add
  % #2 = optional argument for toc and header, as usual
  % #3 = title
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\standardthechapter#1}%
  \nonstandardchapter[#2]{#3}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\standardthechapter}{\thechapter}%
  \NewCommandCopy{\nonstandardchapter}{\chapter}%
  \AddToHook{cmd/chapter/before}{%
    \RenewCommandCopy{\thechapter}{\standardthechapter}%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapfrac}{mm}{$\frac{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}$}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}\label{ch:one}

\ref{ch:one}, \ref{ch:oneandhalf}, \ref{ch:oneplus}, \ref{ch:two}

\additionalchapter{\chapfrac{1}{2}}{First and a half}\label{ch:oneandhalf}

\additionalchapter{\chapfrac{2}{3}}{First and more}\label{ch:oneplus}

\chapter{Second}\label{ch:two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting if these extra chapters could keep track of their total amount and just enumerate themselves, i.e. 1, 1 1/3, 1 2/3, 2, … but that's just a section in chapter's clothing.

Comment: This... doesn't work.

Comment: @nonhuman The example does, so you must be doing something else. Just “doesn't work” won't help in order to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @egreg I think you are using nonstandard tex commands.

Comment: @nonhuman I think you're using an outdated TeX distribution.

Answer (score 2):

This creates an array of chapter "numbers" to be used for `\thechapter`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\csname chapt\arabic{chapter}\endcsname}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{chapt1}{1}
\@namedef{chapt2}{1.5}
\@namedef{chapt3}{II}
\@namedef{chapt4}{C}
\@namedef{chapt5}{$\pi$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\chapter{Fourth}
\chapter{Fifth}
\end{document}
```