# How can I generate test versions?

Tags: exam

I am using the exam document class, but I am not generating the questions with "Begin questions but with Enumerate because the questions are images"

I am looking for a way to generate versions, I am currently struggling.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}



\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{Physics AB: Dynamics Test}{\hspace{8cm}Name:\rule{2cm}{0.5pt}}{\textbf{VERSION A}}
\runningheader{Physics AB: Dynamics Test}
{}
{\textbf{VERSION A}}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\runningfooter{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\centering
\item %1
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{1.JPG}
\item %2
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{2.JPG}
\item %3
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{3.JPG}

\newpage
 

\item %4
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{4.JPG}
\item %5
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{5.JPG}
\item %6
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{6.JPG}

\newpage


\item %7
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{7.JPG}
\item %8
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{8.JPG}
\item %9
   \includegraphics[scale =0.72,valign=t]{9.JPG}

\newpage

\item %10
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{10.JPG}
\item %11
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{11.JPG}
\item %12
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{20.JPG}

\newpage

\item %13
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{12.JPG}
\item %14
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{16.JPG}
\item %15
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{15.JPG}

\newpage

\item %16
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{14.JPG}
\item %17
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{18.JPG}
\item %18
\includegraphics[scale =0.75,valign=t]{19.JPG}


\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, you need to create an array of file names, from which you select one at random.  Easiest is a TikZ array, but fastest is a \csname array.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296125/how-to-randomize-the-order-of-subsections/296165?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C26.1914#296165